# Boric acid ant poison

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I made an ant poison using boric acid and peanut butter for grease eating ants.  They eat the peanut butter (mixed with some olive oil to get it closer to a liquid), but I see a white residue (crystals?) left behind.  How can I get the boric acid dissolved in an oil or grease?

Comment: Add a small amount of a liquid soap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boric acid is soluble in water, not oil.  Pick an [emulsifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion#Emulsifiers) and add it to your ant poison.

Boric acid needs to remain acidic to retain its effectiveness as an ant killer.  Ants deaths due to boric acid poisoning is a topic still up for debate; however, it has been suggested boric acid is a neuro-toxin and that the acid damages one of the organs in an ants digestive system.

Peanut butter is usually slightly acidic; however, your particular mixture may be rendering the boric acid inert.  Solutions of sugar and boric acid with a high pH have been known to pass right through ants doing little harm. Perhaps using an [acidic additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_additive#acids) will increase the bait's effectiveness.

Boric acid in a 1-2% concentration may be ideal if the entire ant colony is targeted. To target the entire colony, enough poison should be used so the ant does not die before it makes it back it its colony.

Answer (score 0):

Try to saturate a little amount of water with boric acid, and then create an emulsion with this saturated solution and your oily concoction. You will need a lot of vigorous agitation, so you perhaps should consider using a blender to produce the emulsion.